# Validar cpf com ajax puchando do mysql

Tags: jquery, ajax

Galera estou tentando validar um cpf com ajax eu busco o cpf no banco para ver se ja existe se existe ele da um alerta e nao submete o formulario se nao existe ele tem que submeter,mas no meu caso ele ta submetendo segue o codigo

html:

```
<div class="container">
        <section>

            <h4 class="pb-2 mt-3">Novo Paciente</h4>
            <form action="paciente-action-inserir.php" method="post" onsubmit="return teste()" class="form-horizontal" id="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">CPF</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cpf"  class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Digite o cpf aqui" id="cpf"  required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome"  class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Digite o nome aqui" id="nome" required="" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Telefone</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="telefone"  class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Digite o telefone aqui" id="telefone" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Digite o email aqui" id="email" required="">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Cadastrar</button>

            </form>
```

js:

```
function teste(){
    let pegar = $("#cpf").val();
    let cpf = pegar.replace(/[.-]/g,"");
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "verificar.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{"cpf": cpf} ,
        success:function(retorno){


            if(retorno['resultado'] != null){
                alert("cpf ja existe");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }

        },
        error:function(){

        }

    })
```

}

php:

```
<?php 
require_once "banco-paciente.php";

$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

$sql = "SELECT cpf FROM pacientes WHERE cpf = '$cpf'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$retorno = array("cpf"=>$cpf, "resultado"=>$result);

echo json_encode($retorno);




?>
```

Comment: Faltou o código PHP. Também se possível posta a estrutura da tabela

Comment: Adriano, não posso garantir que esse seja o caso, mas acredito que quando a consulta no banco de dados não encontra nenhum resultado, ele te retorna um array vazio, não `null`, então ao invés de fazer a comparação `if (retorno.resultado != null)`, você deveria fazer algo como `if (retorno.resultado.length > 0)`

Comment: fiz isso mesma coisa